# Spring Boot 2.0 Actuator git properties not added to /info

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm using `Gradle` with `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7` and have the following plugins applied:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.M7"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "1.4.17"
}
```

`spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency is also there. `git.properties` files is generated correctly to `build/main/resoures` directory. I've also added property `management.info.git.mode=full`. Due to official docs, [git information should be added](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info-git) to `/info` endpoint automatically with [GitInfoContributor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/info/GitInfoContributor.java). However none of the above helps and `/info` endpoint returns empty JSON instead - `{}`. Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

**UPDATE 1**:
What I've found so far is that if I manually copy `git.properties`  to `out/resources`, this way it would work, but they are not put there for some reason.

**UPDATE 2**:
When I run with `gradle bootRun` it works, however when I start it from Intellij IDEA our run `gradle clean build` which runs the test which checks if those properties are displayed on `/info` endpoint - it doesn't work.

Comment: seems as if you need to apply the plugin as well (otherwise the git.properties file is not bundled within the jar): `apply plugin: "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties"`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. With Gradle > 2.1, apply section can be skipped if you specify `plugins` section as far as I know. https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties

Comment: Gets the `git.properties` file packaged with the jar?

Comment: Yes, I see it packaged in `BOOT-INF/classes` dir in jar. Interesting fact I've just found, is that with `gradle bootRun` it works, however when I start it from Intellij IDEA our run `gradle clean build` which runs the test which checks if those properties are displayed on /info - it doesn't work.

Comment: So I think it gets packaged and then it works. However before packaging like running from IDE or running from tests - it doesn't.

Comment: Running from the IDE might not work - because usually this tools package the artifact into a separate (other than gradle/maven( directory for execution.

Comment: @fateddy ok, that's sad. Thanks for the answer, I'll keep digging, maybe there is any solution at least for checking that from tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was running the app from IDE. As the properties are generated on the phase when JAR is assembled, they were not included. Running the application via `java -jar artifact.jar` or `gradle bootRun` works without any issues.

Thanks @fateddy for help on resolving the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure your IDE to call the process-resources maven goal, prior to the Build/Launch, this will cause the git.properties file and build-info.properties files to be generated prior to the application launching.

I use Maven, but a similar configuration should be possible for Gradle.

[image: IntelliJ Build/Run Configuration]

Comment: thanks, that works for running from IDE from Gradle too

Comment: Yes. Gradle has task `processResources`, `processTestResources` and `processItestResources`. And don't run with IDE, run with Gradle.

Answer (score 3):

For IntelliJ IDEA, you can enable **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle option** in Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner tab.